# The Lemoine point and absolute distances

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, optimization, triangles

The point inside a triangle, which minimizes the sum of the absolute distances to the edges, seems to be a different point then the Lemoine point.

How can this point be determined and why might the Lemoine point be preferable?

**Edit:** Since this question has been marked as a possible duplicate, based on the claim that this point and the Lemoine point are the same: They are not.
If you consider the triangle spanned by the points (-2,0), (2,0), (0,2), the total distance to the edges of the point (0,2) is the height 2. This is smaller then the total distance of the Lemoine point to the edges, which is approx. 2.41.

The point with the minimum total distance always seems to come down to the vertex with the minimum height, but I am not shure how to prove it.

**Edit2:** After reconsideration, the answer by Calvin Lin in the referenced question, seems to answer my first question. However, I still wonder, in which cases it might be beneficial to consider the squared instead of the absolute distances.

Comment: see also here http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/fermat_point.shtml

Comment: $L$ Lemoine point gives minimum value of $d(AB,P)^2+d(BC,P)^2+d(CA,P)^2$. Here $P$ is a point on the plane of $\triangle ABC$. There is a paper about properties of Lemoine point: http://www.irmo.ie/7.Lemoine.pdf

Comment: You are talking about Fermat's point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point

Comment: The Fermat Point seems to be the point with the minimum total distance to the vertices. I talk about the point with the minimum total distance to the edges. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [point which minimises the sum of the distances from the sides in a triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463698/point-which-minimises-the-sum-of-the-distances-from-the-sides-in-a-triangle)

Comment: @Michael Palm As the OP says (with a certain doubt ?) it is the Lemoine point. See (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/463698)

Comment: It is not. If you consider the triangle spanned by the points (-2,0), (2,0), (0,2), the total distance to the edges of the point (0,2) is the height 2. This is smaller then the total distance of the Lemoine point to the edges, which is approx. 2.41.

Comment: The point with the minimum total distance always seems to come down to the vertex with the minimum height, but I am not shure how to prove it.

Comment: Hi @MichaelPalm , I think that your problem completly same https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463698/point-which-minimises-the-sum-of-the-distances-from-the-sides-in-a-triangle 
Plesa you could examine ''solution of Calvin Lin''. His solution gives mimimum height of triangle.

Comment: Since you are asking about the *distinction* between the point that minimizes the sum of distances to edges and [the Lemoine point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemoine_point), it would be helpful to Readers if you explain the definition of the latter.  In particular its definition entails the somewhat convoluted notion of *symmedian" lines.

Comment: @Scarface you are right. I didn't notice this. I just saw the reference to the Lemoine point question and  thought "This doesn't answer my question". However, I still wonder, in which cases it might be beneficial to consider the squared distances instead of the absolute distances.

Comment: Hi @MichaelPalm , You seaching $\min\{ h_a, h_b, h_c \}$ or Lemoine distance $\dfrac{4\Delta ^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$ which is smaller? Do I get it right? My opinion $\min\{ h_a, h_b, h_c \} \leq \dfrac{4\Delta ^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$. Because for your examples: ''the triangle spanned by the points $(-2,0), (2,0), (0,2)$ the total distance to the edges of the point $(0,2)$ is the height $2$. This is smaller then the total distance of the Lemoine point to the edges, which is approx. $2.41$''